Firefox doesn't honor cursor theme after update
I run Debian stable (version 12.7) and the Blackbox window manager. After the latest update to Firefox 128.3.1esr (with apt dist-upgrade) the cursor is black in Firefox windows but white elsewhere. My ~/.Xresources contains the line
Xcursor.theme: DMZ-White

which Firefox obviously doesn't use now. I have tried to set the theme with
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme 'DMZ-White'

but that didn't change anything. Any clues?
Edit 2024-10-15: I have also made sure that xdg-desktop-portal-gtk is installed after seeing a proposed solution at https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1434500. For me it was already installed.
$ dpkg -l | grep xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
ii  xdg-desktop-portal-gtk                           1.14.1-1                                  amd64        GTK+/GNOME portal backend for xdg-desktop-portal

Running Firefox with
$ MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=0 firefox

also made no difference.

I have filed a bug report about the issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1925319

The solution can be found here: https://superuser.com/questions/1859868/changing-cursor-theme-in-firefox-for-local-user-on-gnu-linux
