Changing cursor theme in Firefox for local user on GNU/Linux
I run Debian stable (version 12.7) with the Blackbox window manager. In Firefox  128.3.1esr the mouse cursor is black despite the setting
Xcursor.theme: DMZ-White

in ~/.Xresources. When I start the window manager and in all other applications I have tried the cursor is white as expected. What configuration is needed for a local user to make the cursor in Firefox windows white as well? In earlier versions of Firefox the cursor was white with the same setting so I'm thinking that the cursor theme is supposed to be configured in a new way.

In recent versions of Firefox the setting Xcursor.theme is no longer used (apparently). Here is the "new" way to make this setting for a local user:
$ mkdir -p ~/.icons/default
$ ln -s /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme ~/.icons/default/index.theme

To make the setting for all users, run
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme

and select DMZ-White.
